# Different execution time for same query

Tags: mysql, indexing

This is table scheme:(The table is created from [test_db](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db))

```
create table employees
(
    emp_no     int             not null
        primary key,
    birth_date date            not null,
    first_name varchar(14)     not null,
    last_name  varchar(16)     not null,
    gender     enum ('M', 'F') not null,
    hire_date  date            not null
);
create index first_name_idx on employees(first_name);
```

When I run

```
select emp_no, gender from employees where first_name = 'Shahab';
```

for first time, its execution time is about 250ms. But when I rerun the query, its execution time is about 7ms.  And after I run

```
select emp_no, gender from employees use index() where first_name = 'Shahab'
```

reruning

```
select emp_no, gender from employees where first_name = 'Shahab';
```

costs me 250ms again. Why?
I use MySQL 8 on windonw 10 and run these queries in DataGrip

Comment: Try to update table statistic.

Comment: @Spaceship222 - every day's a school day - thanks :) I'll remove my comment above so it doesn't confuse.

Comment: *When I run* The effect of index hint `USE INDEX ()` without indices list is not defined... and it is unknown what happens in this case. Try to use described usage and specify `first_name_idx` or `PRIMARY`.

Comment: @Akina What other statistic should I provide?

Comment: *What other statistic should I provide?* I mean `ANALYZE TABLE`.

Comment: @Akina Any right way to force query to not use index instead of `use index()`

Comment: o_O `IGNORE INDEX (index list)`...

Comment: @Akina Thanks! After I run `analyze table employees`, it has no effect

Comment: Please provide a test case, complete with index / hint changes.  Either that will give us something to work with to help you, or you will discover what when wrong.

Comment: @RickJames Test case? Do you mean example data for table employees?If so, I create such table from [test_db](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db) where all data is from

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each case.